# Deploying Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web-applications

I have the task to deploy web application using instructions. I did it according to instructions but I have a trouble while opening main page of the application:

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
>          ASP.global_asax.GetCurrentUsersDomainName() +312
>          ASP.global_asax.Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) +44
>          System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.CompleteAcquireState() +409
>          System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.BeginAcquireState(Object source, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +1268   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +12335126
>          System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288

Is anybody has thoughts how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

this means you are trying to manipulate a null object, if you can update the question with your code i can exactly tell where the problem is

Comment: Compare your sessions/ strings .. before accessing...   if(session["testsession"] != null) like this...